# How can I change array items?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array containing links. I am trying to cut a part of those links. For example:

```
$array = [
  "https://eksisozluk.com/merve-sanayin-pizzaciya-kapiyi-ciplak-acmasi--5868043?a=popular",
  "https://eksisozluk.com/merve-sanayin-pizzaciya-kapiyi-ciplak-acmasi--5868043?a=popular"
];
```

I want change these links like below:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(91) "https://eksisozluk.com/merve-sanayin"
  [1]=>
  string(91) "https://eksisozluk.com/merve-sanayin"
  [2]=>
}
```

Is there any possible way to edit array items?

Comment: `array_map()` will iterate the array, as will a `for()` or a `foreach()` loop.

Comment: And then you can handle each entry one by one and reassign whatever value you want.

Comment: Hi Barbie, welcome on Stack overflow. you can use `array_walk` or `array_map` along with `str_replace` or `preg_replace`.

Comment: @Barbie  a better solution is:- https://3v4l.org/S4VU1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways. One way is to iterate over the items and clip them with substr().

```
$arr = array("https://eksisozluk.com/merve-sanayin-pizzaciya-kapiyi-ciplak-acmasi--5868043?a=popular",
"https://eksisozluk.com/merve-sanayin-pizzaciya-kapiyi-ciplak-acmasi--5868043?a=popular");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
    $arr[$i] = substr($arr[$i], 0, 36);
}
```

Comment: it will not work if count changed from 36 .(no of characters counted before second -) .Check here:- https://3v4l.org/a4GQo

Answer (score 1):

Given the array:

```
$array = [
    "https://eksisozluk.com/merve-sanayin-pizzaciya-kapiyi-ciplak-acmasi--5868043?a=popular",
    "https://eksisozluk.com/merve-sanayin-pizzaciya-kapiyi-ciplak-acmasi--5868043?a=popular"
];
```

#### Using [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) (modifies the array in place).

Using a regular expression this time:

```
function filter_url(&$item)
{
    preg_match('|(https:\/\/\w+\.\w{2,4}\/\w+-\w+)-.+|', $item, $matches);
    $item = $matches[1];
}

array_walk($array, 'filter_url');
```

(See it working [here](https://3v4l.org/V1UnL)).

Note that `filter_url` passes the first parameter by reference, as explained in the documentation, so changes to each of the array items are performed in place and affect the original array.

#### Using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) (returns a modified array)

Simply using `substr`, since we know next to nothing about your actual requirements:

```
function clean_url($item)
{
    return substr($item, 0, 36);
}

$new_array = array_map('clean_url', $array);
```

Working [here](https://3v4l.org/iGgkV).

---

The specifics of *how* actually filter the array elements are up to you.

The example shown here seems kinda pointless, since you are setting all elements exactly to the same value. If you know the lenght you can use `substr`, or you could just could write a more robust regex.

Since all the elements of your input array are the same in the example, I am going to assume this doesn't represent your actual input.

You could also iterate the array using either `for`, `foreach` or  `while`, but either of those options seems less elegant when you have specific array functions to deal with this kind of situation.

Comment: Good demonstration of those methods. You might want to point out that the ampersand `&` is needed for array_walk() to modify the value and explain that it means `$item` is a reference.